# Getting Styles.Render() to preserve indentation from Razor template?

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, indentation, bundling-and-minification

I'm slightly obsessive about the readability (and hence indentation) of all markup.

When I call `@Styles.Render("~/content/css")` in an ASP.NET MVC4 project, **only the first line maintains indentation** from my Razor template.

Here is the output:

```
    <link href="/Content/css/ie.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/css/1140.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/css/screen.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/css/compatibility.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

I would prefer all generated markup have the same indentation as the `@Styles.Render()` call.

Is this easily done? If so, how?

Comment: If it matters, when you deploy this project, the only thing that will render is  `<link href="/Content/css?v=somenumber" rel="stylesheet"/>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ideally the rendered HTML would be minified. Formatted markup is great while developing but makes for a bigger file if that is what you are serving to the user.

The only reason you see four style sheets is that you are running in a debug environment, which has disabled your bundling. As I explained in the post "[Scripts.Render using outdated javascript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570171/scripts-render-using-outdated-javascript-file/14570455#14570455)" if you add `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;` to the bottom of your `RegisterBundles` in your `BundleConfig`, it will force bundling to work (as it would in release mode), and you'll see that this:

```
    <link href="/Content/css/ie.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/css/1140.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/css/screen.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/css/compatibility.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

now renders as this:

```
    <link href="/Content/css?v=Sn3f8Vf56Sr9k0EreIZnouVoGt2cfrd41" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

So yes while developing, it isn't maintaining your indentation, but once you publish it will be what you want.