# StyleBundle shows 404 when published to Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-4.5, bundling-and-minification

I know there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595405/404-errors-on-bundled-jquery-css-vs2012-publishing-to-azure) but the cause of the problem is different.

In my global.asax I am bundling two files:

```
Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim cssBundle As New StyleBundle("~/bundles/bundle1")
    cssBundle.Include("~/css/normalize.css", "~/css/main.css")
    BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = True
    BundleTable.Bundles.Add(cssBundle)
End Sub
```

In my Master page I then output:

```
<head runat="server">
    <%= System.Web.Optimization.Styles.Render("~/bundles/bundle1") %>
</head>
```

When running locally the browser renders this and everything works perfectly:

```
<link href="/bundles/bundle1?v=fU8Z_qH3ecSnJ9aM3BZrgcpbwQzeNBiu8CxQz5Pwbkw1" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

When published to Azure however, only this is rendered and Firebug shows a 404 being returned:

```
<link href="/bundles/bundle1" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Scott Mitchell has [posted a solution to a similar problem](http://scottonwriting.net/sowblog/archive/2013/10/19/asp-net-bundling-and-minification-returning-file-not-found-404.aspx), however his fix was a typo.  There are no typo's here (that I can see).  The `\bundles\` does not physically exist so cannot conflict (which I believe is the correct approach).

Comment: Yes it's the correct approach. If there was a directory or file called `/bundles/bundle1` then it would break... what version of Optimization are you using?

Comment: Hi @MikeSmithDev. It's version `1.1.31028.0` acccording to the DLL properties.