# Basic Bundling, Minification in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

ASP.NET MVC 4.0 application - Visual Studio 2012

I cannot get bundling and minification to work in release mode.

My basic non-understanding is:

Do I have to provide the *.**MIN**.css, *.**MIN**.js files beforehand, or should VS minify the files on its own? (ie: I provide a mcimagemanager.js and VS makes a mcimagemanager.MIN.js out of it) ???

Here is a code snippet - which gets called in Global.asax:

```
 public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
       var im = new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/MCImageManager").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/tinymce/plugins/imagemanager/js/mcimagemanager.js"
                    );
        bundles.Add(im);
    }
```

it works fine in Debug - not in Release-mode

Thank you!

Comment: I think the bundler will look for the normal js/css file with a .min at the end but can also generate these minified files too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you don't need to provide `.min` file, nor will the bundler create that version (not something you see in the folder, at least).

The difference is this. Let's say you have both `jquery-1.9.1.js` and `jquery-1.9.1.min.js` in your scripts folder.

**Debug mode** will use `jquery-1.9.1.js` as the source script, and no it won't be minified or bundled, as the whole bundling/minification is disabled in debug mode (though you can override this).

**Release mode** will use `jquery-1.9.1.min.js` AND bundle it with other scripts for that bundle.

If you only have the one file, `jquery-1.9.1.js`, Release mode will use it and minify and bundle it.

Debug mode will NOT use `.min` files. So if you use a wildcard to include all files for a scripts directory, your .min files will not be included.

Debug mode, if you look at the rendered HTML, will reference all script files in the bundle *individually*. In Release mode, there will only be one script reference (with a querystring for versioning) per bundle.

Other relevant reading/posts:

[Scripts.Render using outdated javascript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570171/scripts-render-using-outdated-javascript-file/14570455#14570455)

[Force ASP.Net MVC Bundle to render the javascript files in a certain order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14563415/force-asp-net-mvc-bundle-to-render-the-javascript-files-in-a-certain-order/14563828#14563828)

Answer (score 1):

Bundling and minification framework do also minification itself. So you just provide plain JavaScript/CSS files. It handle on the one hand files itself in the other hand it handle the registration in the view, for eample: `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")`. So it "know" what file needs to be included in the view, weather it is "normal" or "min" version.

More on that topic you can find in this nice Exercise: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs11trainingcourse_aspnetandvisualstudio_topic5.aspx

However this is might even better resource for the MVC oriented application: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification